# To print only one occurrence of matching pattern using pcregrep

Tags: python, regex

Is there any option in pcregrep that allows me to print only one occurrence of the matched string pattern? I came to know about option --match-limit. But pcregrep is not recognizing this options. Is there any specific version that supports this option.

I assume that `--match-limit=1` prints only one occurrence of the matched pattern.

You can also let me know on other possible ways. I am executing pcregrep command from a python script via commands utility of python.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: @devnull: I am looking for pcregrep nor normal grep command

Comment: FYI, I added references to the answer, as well as examples of the `-c` and `-l` options which are closer to your needs than `--match-limit=1`, but not exactly it.

Comment: @zx81: I don't think so -c will work for me...and -l i don't need it because it prints the matching file names instead of lines

Comment: @suresh that is all I can do, I hope my answer was helpful in some way, that is all the information I am able to dig up. Please also test -M on your system as per my comment.

Comment: Hey suresh, did my answer solve it, or are you still struggling with it?

Answer (score 1):

Before we look into --match-limit, let's review two options that *almost* do what you want to do.

**Option 1.** When you only want to know if you can find a match in a file, but you don't care what the match is, you can use the -l option like so:

```
pcregrep  -l \d\d\d test.txt
```

where `\d\d\d` is the pattern and test.txt contains the strings.

**Option 2.** To count the number of matches, use

```
pcregrep  -c \d\d\d test.txt
```

This may be the closest we can get to what you want to do.

**What is `match--limit` ?**

`--match-limit=1`does work, but it doesn't do what you want it to do.

From the documentation:

> The --match-limit option provides a means of limiting resource usage
>   when processing patterns that are not going to match, but which have a
>   very large number of possibilities in their search trees. The classic
>   example is a pattern that uses nested unlimited repeats. Internally,
>   PCRE uses a function called match() which it calls repeatedly
>   (sometimes recursively). The limit set by --match-limit is imposed on
>   the number of times this function is called during a match, which has
>   the effect of limiting the amount of backtracking that can take place.

So `--match-limit` is about memory, not about the number of matches.

**Let's try this out:**

If you make a file called test.txt and add some lines with three digits, like so:

```
111
123
456
```

Then running `pcregrep  --match-limit=1 \d\d\d test.txt` will match all these lines.

But if you run pcregrep  `--match-limit=1 \d{3} test.txt` you will get an error that `the resource limit was exceeded`.

Looking at the full documentation, I don't see any option to limit the number of matches. Of course you could design your regex to do so.

**For more info**

1. You probably know this, but for the short documentation type `pcregrep --help`
2. The full documentation can be downloaded in the pcre package from [pcre.org](http://www.pcre.org)
3. For usage examples, see [grep in PCRE](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even I realized the same there is no option readily available for pcregrep to limit the number of prints that matches the given pattern. How can I design my regular expression to limit the number of matches?

Comment: @suresh Actually my last suggestions -c and -l are the best I can find. On Windows, I am not getting Multiline mode to work with `pcregrep -M ^(?s).*?\d\d\d.*$ test.txt` Maybe on your unix. Otherwise -c and -l are quite good.

Comment: @suresh I am going to bed now. But hey, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer gives the answer to your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark and arrow on the left, as this is how the reputation system works. Of course there is no obligation to do so. Upvoting answers that are helpful by clicking the "up" arrows on the left also helps the system. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO tutorial. :)